# Is passed data to a php page using .load method of ajax can be used by $_REQUEST method only

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to treat passed data to a php page with $_POST OR $_GET rather than $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for get http get request and [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for http post request and on server side $_GET for handling get request and $_POST for post request.

Comment: Is netscape navigator also support this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
If you do something like this:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html?var1=somevar&var2=someothervar', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

You can retrieve it with `$_GET[''];`.

If you do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/',
    data: {var1:"somevar", etc.}, // I'm not really sure about that syntax
    type:'POST', // note the type
    success:function(html){ alert(html) }
});
```

You can retrieve it with `$_POST[''];`.

There are other ways for both POST and GET, those were the first I found on google ;)
You can always retrieve it with `$_REQUEST[''];` because that looks for both POST and GET data, in case you didn't already know.